# Problem with numeric keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Z50-70 notebook and although my numeric keyboard is activate or not (using the NUMLOCK key), it is not functioning.

I tried to look throughout forums and the System Settings but I cant find a proper way to use it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you choose the correct keyboard layout?